# How to make loading screen for a canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm working with javascript canvas element, and I was looking for ways that I could make a loading screen for it, as it needs to lay out two hundred thousand individually colored dots on the screen, and it takes quite a while. All of the loading screen things I saw were jQuery solutions for the HTML elements loading. However, the canvas tag loads fast, but the elements on it do not. Is there any way to gauge the progress of the canvas loading?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myContext = myCanvasElement.getContext('2d'),
myImg = new Image();
var img=document.getElementById("scream");

myImg.onload = function() {
    myContext.drawImage(img, 300, 300);
    //...
    //...
    //your "on-finished" Call Here
};
```

canva context functions are synchronous themselves.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a div with absolute position then position it over your canvas.

```
//Init Canvas... get context
//blah blah blah

//Put a load screen over it
var loading=$('<div style="position:absolute;left:;top:;background:url(\'loading.gif\' white"/>').appendTo("body");

//Call drawing procedure
//......

//when done just remove
loading.remove()
```

Comment: Before you draw something, call the loadscreen, after draw, remove it